# deselect header checkbox when a checkbox is unchecked

Tags: jtable, jcheckbox

i have a jtable with a checkbox in the header and other checkbox in the cell of the column.

like you can see on the picture, there are a problem
[image]

boolean is used for the first colum for the DefaultTableModel

right now,  i have a tableRenderer for my first column

what option should  i use to make header to get deselected if a check box is deselected?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have an actionevent for the top checkbox, and on checked or unchecked, run a for loop to check/uncheck all the checkboxes in the table.

Comment: not really answer the question.... if the header is checked.... so all checkbox is checked.... if the user uncheck one of theses checkbox, the header chekbox need to be unchecked

Comment: I think you need to implement this in the hard way only. ie, have an action listener for each of the check boxes, and on unchecking any of it, uncheck the "select all" option

Comment: maybe with a TableModelListener, there are something to do

Answer (score 0):

That would be very easy. Register a listener to the table model:

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(listener);
```

Look at the event, if the value changed was from the first column and it was set to false then deselect the checkbox.